# Socketio not connecting with localhost and DigitalOcean App Platform

Tags: node.js, socket.io, digital-ocean

I have a nodejs backend with an express server and react native (expo) frontend. Socketio was working before I started hosting the server on the digitalocean app platform. I have a basic messaging app to send messages and display them in realtime. I also switched to using a postgres database on digitalocean and that's working.

index.js for the server:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = express();
const host = "0.0.0.0";
const myRouter = require("./routers.js");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const authRouter = require("./routers/authRouter");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const pool = require("./db");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use("/auth", authRouter);

app.use("/backend", myRouter);

const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    // origin: "https://my-app-domain.ondigitalocean.app",
    // origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    origin: "127.0.0.1:3000",
    credentials: true,
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");

  socket.on("insert msg return updated list", (req) => {
    const firstQuery = pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO messages(sender_id, group_id, text) values ($1, $2, $3)",
      [req.userId, req.currentGroup, req.mymessage]
    );

    pool.query(
      "SELECT username sender_username, text, messages.id messages_id, to_json(messages.created_at) iso_time_sent FROM messages INNER JOIN users ON messages.sender_id = users.id WHERE messages.group_id = $1 ORDER BY messages.created_at DESC",
      [req.currentGroup],
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        io.emit("insert msg return updated list", res.rows);
      }
    );
  });
 
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user disconnected");
  });
});

app.use(
  cors({
    //  origin: "https://my-app-domain.ondigitalocean.app",
    //  origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    origin: "127.0.0.1:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.listen(PORT, host, function () {
  console.log("listening on port " + PORT);
});
```

The commented out lines are things I've tried to get cors working, thinking maybe I need to change the origin for cors.

The frontend socket.js:

```
const { io } = require("socket.io-client");

const socket = io("https://my-app-domain.ondigitalocean.app", {
  autoConnect: false,
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default socket;
```

I have autoconnect off, because I connect when the user logs in on the home page, and disconnect on logout (was working fine before moving to digitalocean app platform):

From HomeScreen.jsx:

```
  if (user.loggedIn === true) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      socket.connect();
    }, []);
  } else {
    socket.disconnect();
  }

  const signOut = () => {
    SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("userToken");
    setUser({ loggedIn: false });
    socket.disconnect();
  };
```

Then the screen where I use socketio (the only thing I changed since moving to the app platform is the domain for the fetch request to get messages):

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Button,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Text,
  Alert,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import { Formik, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import { globalStyles } from "../../styles/global";
const { addMessageSchema } = require("../validationSchema");
import { AccountContext } from "../AccountContext";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import socket from "../../socket";
import moment from "moment";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";

export default function ChatScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [chats, setChats] = React.useState([]);

  const scrollViewRef = React.useRef();

  const getChats = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://my-app-domain.ondigitalocean.app/backend/getmessages",
        {
          method: "POST",
          credentials: "include",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ ...user }),
        }
      );
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      setChats(jsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };


  React.useEffect(() => {
    getChats();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("insert msg return updated list", (jsonData) => {
      setChats(jsonData);
      getChats();
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        onContentSizeChange={() =>
          scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })
        }
        style={{
          width: "90%",
        }}
      >
        {chats &&
          chats.map((chats) => {
            return (
              <View
                key={chats.messages_id}
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "transparent",
                  padding: 5,
                  marginTop: 10,
                  marginRight: 40,
                }}
              >
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    alignItems: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", color: "#333" }}>
                    {chats.sender_username}
                  </Text>
                  <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 2 }}></View>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: "grey" }}>
                    {moment(chats.iso_time_sent).calendar()}
                  </Text>
                 </View>
                <Text style={{ color: "#333" }}>{chats.text}</Text>
              </View>
            );
          })}
      </ScrollView>
      <View>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{ mymessage: "" }}
          validationSchema={addMessageSchema}
          onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
            const vals = { ...values };
            const uservals = { ...user, ...values };
            actions.resetForm();
            socket.emit("insert msg return updated list", uservals);
          }}
        >
          {(props) => (
            <View>
              <View>
                <TextInput
                  style={globalStyles.input}
                  placeholder="Send message..."
                  onChangeText={props.handleChange("mymessage")}
                  value={props.values.mymessage}
                  marginBottom={10}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={globalStyles.sendButton}
                  onPress={props.handleSubmit}
                >
                  <Text style={globalStyles.primaryButtonText}>Send</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Once again, everything was working when it was all on localhost, so I'm assuming I have something wrong with cors configuration or the urls. This is my first time using digitalocean app platform.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to change index.js to have this for the server instead of what I had before (I had the other stuff back when I was trying to use heroku). This is what worked:

```
server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("server listening on port 8080");
});
```

Comment: one more thing, You can get rid of body parser since it comes by default with express now